# Famous songs recorded and edited with Audacity?

Tags: audacity, production, request, engineering, recordings

What famous songs (classical or any other genera) have been recorded and edited with Audacity?

In other words: Do professional sound engineers use Audacity for production releases?

Comment: It's more likely for rough or demo versions to be created by the artist in open source software, but then be re-recorded and processed with high end equipment for release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four Tet regularly uses Audacity and to answer Clark's question, familiarity with the software.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are plenty of recordings done with Audacity, but why would a professional use it while there are many more functional programs available?

In a pinch, it would work well enough.